# Android Studio Oracle JDBC, keep getting null for resultSet

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdbc

I am working on my senior project for school and I am running into a problem. For some reason when I try to pull the user's first and last name off of our database I keep getting null. I know that the JDBC is working properly because our login works correctly. Here is some of my code to show you whats going on.

Account Fragment

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // initialize your views

        TextView mTextView1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        mTextView1.setText(UserLoginInfo.fName + " " + UserLoginInfo.lName);


        TextView mTextView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        mTextView2.setText(UserLoginInfo.userEmail);

    }
}
```

UserLoginInfo Class

```
public class UserLoginInfo {
public static String userEmail;
public static String fName;
public static String lName;


public UserLoginInfo() throws SQLException {

    try {
        Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

        Statement st = null;

        st = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        if(st!=null)
            resultSet = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email=" + userEmail + "'");
        if(resultSet!=null) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                fName = resultSet.getString("firstname");
                lName = resultSet.getString("lastname");
            }
        }

        resultSet.close();
        st.close();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Keep in mind that the login does work. So I don't understand why I keep getting null for fName and lName. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: ResultSet.next() moves to the next row. I suppose, all your corresponding data lies in the same row. So you don't need the second while.

Comment: Yeah I have tried doing that in a separate class and it still didn't work.

Comment: Please add your query to the question.

Comment: Is fName null after setting getString or just because that part of code wasn't executed? What does this function return: true or false?

Comment: Can you execute your query from SQL*Plus or any other DB viewer? Does it return values for `firstname`?

Comment: I updated my question. Changed my code around a little bit so it is a little less confusing. All I am trying to do is retrieve the user's first name and last name from the database and put it into a textview in android studio. The result is "null null".

Comment: Can you run a debugger on that code? Does it actually return null from calling "getString" or it just doesn't reach that part? What if you try getString( 1 ), getString( 2 ) - i.e. retrieving value by column position instead of column name? Are you sure that no errors are logged?

Comment: Yes I have tried using the getString(1) and getString(2) with no luck. Currently I am getting an error in the Android Device Monitor tool on when I try to create an instance of type UserLoginInfo.

Comment: Please add the error stack trace to the question. By the way, don't forget to close the connection. And yes, @user245259 is right: it would be easier to find a problem in a standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

In the query string `"SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email=" + userEmail + "'"`, there is a ' missing.

BTW It is a terrible idea to use `executeQuery` like that. It opens doors to SQL injection attack. Use prepared statement instead.
[Prepared Statement Usage.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Thank you for noticing that but it still does not work. I am still kind of new to using the JDBC but I might try using prepared statement instead.

Comment: Can you run the UserLoginInfo Class in a standalone java app, since it's not depending on other android related things, and see what the result would be?